# RAD - Websphere Application server won't start

Tags: java, websphere

I am having issues with RAD7.

My server will not start for me today.  I am working from home and connected to the VPN.  Everything works except my server in RAD.  It worked fine yesterday in work and had previously worked when I was at home but that was a few weeks ago.

Are there any settings that I should look out for?  I have disabled my proxy settings in RAD and turned off everything in my firewall.  I can ping all the DBs that the server is connecting to.

I have even removed all the projects from the server and it will still not start.  It keeps trying and then times out after 300s.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

I got a similar error while Starting WebSphere Commerce server v7. This error in my case was caused by me increasing the Maximum Heap size to 2096. I reduced the heap size to 1536 and it worked. None of the errors/trace files indicated this problem.

Comment: Thank you. I changed maximumHeapSize from 2048 to 1024 in _[IBM_ROOT_DIR]/WebSphere/[WASVersion]/AppServer/profiles/[MyProfile]/config/cells/MyCell/nodes/MyNode/servers/MyServer/server.xml_ and it worked

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too.  Double-click on the server to open the server 'OVERVIEW' tab/view.  Scroll down to the section under 'Optimize server start for development:'; uncheck 'Start server with a generated script'.  This worked for me.  good luck.

Comment: This worked a treat for me also, thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I have had this problem once before.  I wasn't able to figure out what went wrong, but deleting that server and creating a new one (under Window -> Preferences -> Server -> WebSphere Application Server) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Re the file not found exception.  Make sure the directory path in Windows is of the CoRRectCase, e.g., GALFTGA342130Node01Cell-> galftga342130Node01Cell. I've encountered this on various RAD installations.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to your following comment -

> I looked at startserver.log and I saw a file not found exception for this file C:\IBM\SDP70\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\AppSrv01\config\cells\GALFTGA342130Node0‌​1Cell\nodes\GALFTGA342130Node01\serverindex.xml. I checked and the file exists but when I try to open it, I get told access denied.

this [link](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21378393) may help you in understanding the problem. it says -

> This is a permissions issue caused by the automatic port detection routine. If any profiles already exist and were created as a different user, the port detection routine will try to open the serverindex.xml file in each profile and will fail.

You should set appropriate permissions for your user.

Answer (score 0):

after working several hours in my case I found the solution I hope it works for you ; change my JDK to alternate JRE